# Truncate and load DynamoDb or SCD Type 1 DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Here is my use case.. please let me know if there is a better approach to achieve this.

I have 400 Million records loaded to a dynamodb table..
(id, datapoint) where id is identifier and datapoint is a json string.

I got to maintain this table continuously with out downtime but the challenge is data keeps changing.

Currently my glue job loads data to s3 file which takes around 1.5hrs and another glue job loads s3 to dynamodb load takes about 4hrs.

Option 1: Load the data to temp table.. then swap the tables i.e. rename target table to temp and temp to tgt. But seem renaming is not an option in Dynamo and alternative for that is to restore the backup to new table. But don't know if we can do this through glue or lambda? Looks like even this take few hours which means table will be down.

Option 2: truncate the load the target table. But looks like there is no truncate in dynamo again I would have to delete the table and recreate it.. is this possible to create a table through aws glue. Again there will be downtime for the table in this scenario.

Could you please advise if there is a better approach to get this requirement done.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question what exactly you're trying to do. What do you mean by "maintain this table"? Do you need to modify each row regularly? If so, why don't you do in-place changes?